# $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10 Infinite Scroll not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, scroll, infinite

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'getcontent.php',
        data: 'lastid=' + 0,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#content").append(data);
        }
    });

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
            var last_id = $(".entries:last").attr("id");
            loadMoreData(last_id);
        }
    });

    function loadMoreData(last_id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'getcontent.php',
            data: 'lastid=' + last_id,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#content").append(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include_once("Medoo.php");

use Medoo\Medoo;

$database = new Medoo([
    'database_type' => 'sqlite',
    'database_file' => 'db.db'
]);

$lastid = $_POST['lastid'];
//$lastid = 10;
$lastid += 1;
$html = "";
$content = $database->select("entries", ["id", "entry"], ["id[<>]" => [$lastid, $lastid + 9]]);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($content); $i++) {
    $html .= "<p class='entries' id='" . $content[$i]["id"] . "'>" . $content[$i]["entry"] . "</p>";
}
echo $html;
?>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

p {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="getcontent.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Infinite scroll is not working, as soon as I scroll down `jQuery` loads all entries instead of only one block of data. Any ideas? 
I think this is causing the malfunction:

> $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() -
>   10

But I'm not sure. I tried different things, also things from tutorials and fiddles but nothing really works. My `php` file is fine, it returns 10 objects from database.

Comment: Do you have in CSS `html, body { height: 100%; }` ? I believe this is crucial for document height to work. Perhaps try `$(document.body).height()` instead.

Comment: I replaced the if condition to document.body.offsetHeight < window.innerHeight + document.body.scrollTop + 100 and now it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was it: document.body.offsetHeight < window.innerHeight + document.body.scrollTop + 100